# Incremental for-loop in twig

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

I'm trying to add values in an array using twig. Does twig have an incremental for-loop feature? I'm aware of the standard for-loop in twig (e.g. {% for k in v %}), but I'm interested in a loop where I may specify things as detailed below in pure PHP:

```
<?php
//adding values in an array
$quantities = array('23', '23', '4', '45', '45');
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($quantities); $i++) {
    $sum += $quantities[$i];    
}
echo "Sum: " . $sum . "\n";
?>
```

This is pretty much exactly what I'm looking to do with twig.

Thanks for any help, All.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Loop options](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) in Twig

```
{% for quantity in quantities %}
   // Do your stuff here with each individual quantity
   // If you want to access the index ($i in your php sample)
   {{ quantities[loop.index0] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Just take it as a reference and check the link provided to adapt it to your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach could be improved even in php "*natively*"

Do you know about [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)?

And of course, in twig you can create a [twig_extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) that in tandem with twig_filter could help you obtain what you want in a smart way.

To create a twig_extension with custom filter (remember to follow link that I have provided for "twig estension"):

```
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFilter('sum', 'array_sum'),
    );
}
```

Then you can use sum keyword into your twig template, as a filter of course

```
{% set sum = quantities|array_sum %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the twig representation of your PHP code, this will be:

```
{% set sum = 0 %}
{% for value in quantities %}
  {% set sum = sum + value %}
{% endfor %}
Sum: {{ sum }}
```

Anyway, @DonCallisto's approach is better.